# Why does an empty infinite loop use my whole CPU?

Tags: c++, performance

I'm running a simple infinite loop in C++:

```
int main() {
  for (;;) {}
}
```

and when I compile and run it, the program consumes 100% of my CPU.  Why does this happen?  I'm using g++ 4.7 on a Macbook Pro.

Comment: Do you understand what this program does?

Comment: What do you expect?

Comment: Did you compile this at maximum optimization level? GCC in fact  *can* turn infinite loops into finite loops, but will not do so unless you tell it too. (Also, I think this might be specific to G++. Your code is also valid in C, but C doesn't have an explicit rule for infinite loops IIRC)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

CPUs run the code they are given as fast as they can. If there is nothing much else of interest going on, the OS will give as much CPU time as possible to the process that wants it. If you were to run *two* of these processes at the same time, they would each get roughly 50% of the CPU time. (Note that the terms used to describe CPU usage get a bit fuzzy if you have more than one core, as virtually all modern CPUs do. If you have a quad core system, the above loop would take 100% of one core, or 25% overall.)

Compute-bound programs that do not do I/O (or otherwise wait for anything external) all behave in this same way.

Comment: Thank you!  I expected that the CPU would not waste CPU running such a simple program (no memory allocation, computations, etc.) but it seems that I was wrong!

Comment: CPUs do exactly what you tell them to do, nothing more, nothing less. :)

Comment: If CPUs were smart enough not to execute code with no aide effects, you would have solved the Halting Problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a quick look at the assembly you will see:

```
.L2:
    jmp     .L2
    .cfi_endproc
```

So the compiler generated a jump instruction.
The CPU just does what it is instructed to: jump around.
You could ask why the compiler generated this code.

Repro:

```
gcc -S test.c -o test.s; more test.s
```